# load xfbml content without the connect login button

Tags: facebook

i have an iframe php application. i want to use xfbml on my page. 
the problem is i am only able to initialize and use xfbml when i use the `connect login button`
the regular `FB.init` is not working...
please help.

```
<fb:login-button>Login button</fb:login-button>
<script src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  

FB.init("e5ff43db9aa3533917e18106796e536f", "http://www.amit-verma.com/roadies/xd_receiver.php"); 
FB.ensureInit(function() { 
    FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("email"); 
    });



/*
FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function(){ 
    FB.Facebook.init("e5ff43db9aa3533917e18106796e536f", "http://www.amit-verma.com/roadies/xd_receiver.php");
```

//  });
*/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anybody else is having the same problem, configure your Base Domain URL. that'll do the trick.